# Ways to say 'rather than'

Tags: grammar, particle-より

> I like cats rather than dogs
>   犬**より**猫が好き
>   犬**よりも**猫が好き
>   犬**というより**猫が好き

Which, if any, of the above are correct and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. 犬より猫が好き
> 2. 犬よりも猫が好き
> 3. 犬というより猫が好き
> 4. 犬ではなく猫が好き

These are all grammatical.

Sentences 1 and 2 sound almost the same to me, but the latter may be slightly more emphatic. They mean "I like cats more than dogs." When the speaker likes both dogs and cats, but has to tell which he likes more, these are the natural choices.

Sentence 4 means "I like cats, but not dogs."

Sentence 3 is semantically closer to Sentence 4, but sounds much milder and euphemistic. It sounds as if he were saying "I don't *particularly* like dogs, but I like cats."

So I think Sentence 3 is the one that is closest to "I like cats rather than dogs."

Comment: The way I understand ではなく is that it's a more formal version of ではなくて (even less formal versions are じゃなく and じゃなくて). So basically we have a verb here (or an い-adjective) in the て form which makes it clear that there are 2 clauses connected with the て form.